# How to Autowire repository interfaces in Components in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring + Mysql and I can Autowire successfully my classes that extended from `PagingAndSortingRepository<T,E>` in my `RepositoryRestController` class.

I can autowire the my repositories in controller below.

```
package com.fallavi.api.user.controller;

import com.fallavi.api.MyConfig;
import com.fallavi.api.purchase.model.Purchase;
import com.fallavi.api.purchase.repository.PurchaseRepository;
import com.fallavi.api.reader.model.Reader;
import com.fallavi.api.reader.repository.ReaderRepository;
import com.fallavi.api.user.calculator.UserCreditHelper;
import com.fallavi.api.user.exceptions.UserCanNotFindException;
import com.fallavi.api.user.model.UserCreditEnoughModel;
import com.fallavi.api.user.model.UserCreditModel;
import com.fallavi.api.user.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserCreditController {

    @Autowired
    private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    @GetMapping(
            value = "/userHasCreditEnough/{reader_id}",
            headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserCreditEnoughModel> userHasCreditEnough(
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token,
            @PathVariable Long reader_id) {

        UserCreditHelper userCreditHelper = new UserCreditHelper();

        // Find user ID from authorization code START //
        Long userID = usersRepository.getUserIDByAuthToken(token);
        if (userID == null) {
            throw new UserCanNotFindException();
        }
        // Find user ID from authorization code END //

        // Find user credit START //
        List<Purchase> purchaseList = this.purchaseRepository.findByUserID(userID);
        Integer userCreditLeft = userCreditHelper.userCreditLeft(purchaseList);
        // Find user credit END //

        // Find user's credit left for Reader START //
        Reader reader = this.readerRepository.findByReaderID(reader_id);
        boolean isUserCreditEnough = userCreditHelper.userHasCreditEnough(userCreditLeft, reader);
        // Find user's credit left for Reader END //

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserCreditEnoughModel(isUserCreditEnough, reader.getOnline()));
    }
}
```

Sure I want to seperate all layers as service, repository and Controller it is why I creating a new helper class that is service layer.

```
@Service
public class UserCreditHelper {

   @Autowired
   UsersRepository usersRepository;

   ....some methods...
}
```

In order to call `UserCreditHelper` class in I am using `ApplicationContext` in my controller class sample below.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserCreditController {

    @Autowired
    private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    @GetMapping(
            value = "/userHasCreditEnough/{reader_id}",
            headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> userHasCreditEnough(
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token) {

        // com.fallavi.api.user.calculator is the package of UserCreditHelper.
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( "com.fallavi.api.user.calculator" );

        return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
    }
}
```

When I tried to request `/userHasCreditEnough/{reader_id}` endpoint it gives error alltime.

`"Error creating bean with name 'userCreditHelper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fallavi.api.user.repository.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}",`

Comment: Why do you create a new application context with that additional package only? You should configure your existing context to include that package.

Comment: Don't...Please don't... Unless you want to run into weird transaction issue, memory issues, performance degradation etc. Each time you do `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( "com.fallavi.api.user.calculator" )` you are reloading your whole application!. Just use dependency injection, you are trying to make things more complex than needed.

Comment: Thanks for comment @dunni 
Could you give an example how I need to create context to us getBeans() method.
I don't know how I need to use context.

Comment: Thanks for comment @M.Deinum, but I really newbie at Spring and I don't know wht is the correct way to create context. COuld u give an example?

Comment: You shouldn't... Just auto wire the beans you need and make sure everything else is scanned. Don't create a context yourself.

Comment: In my case `UserCreditHelper` have userRepository, but I don't know how I should call `UserCreditHelper` in `UserCreditController` to create dependency. When I create new UserCreditHelper(), userRepository returns null. @M.Deinum

Comment: As stated using auto wiring... You are autowiring the repositories as well, why should this be different.

Comment: Shame on me I found to create correct way to create context I only 
@Autowired
 private ApplicationContext appContext;

Comment: You don't need that, just do `@Autowire UserCreditHelper`. UserCreditHelper is already a Spring bean, so you can directly autowire it instead of going through the appContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an interface which will be your service layer. Then inject that interface into the controller and call the desire methods in the desire end point of the controller. From there call the implantation you want from this injected interface.

Comment: Your welcome. You can check the spring configuration about spring boot services and how to implement the desire implementation for each controller you like. It is super easy and they also provide good examples for it. @MustafaOlkun